# DynamicObject returned by dapper query doesn't contain all selected columns

Tags: .net, sql-server, orm, dapper, calculated-columns

I'm using dapper.net to execute an insert as follows:

```
var columns = conn.Query("INSERT INTO MyTable" +
                   "(Col1, Col2, Col3)" +
                   "VALUES (@Col1, @Col2, @Col3)" +
                   "SELECT Id, ComputedColumn FROM MyTable WHERE Id = scope_identity()",
                   myObj).Single();

myObj.Id = columns.Id;
myObj.ComputedValue = columns.ComputedColumn;
```

The query succeeds, but an exception is thrown at `myObj.ComputedValue = columns.ComputedColumn;` saying `'System.Dynamic.DynamicObject' does not contain a definition for 'ComputedColumn'`

As you might have gathered, ComputedColumn is a computed column on the table, which is why I'm returning it after the insert along with the Id.  Any idea why this would be failing?

Comment: Can you post your table structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out -- I had a instead-of-insert trigger on this table.  The trigger was returning the Id in order to play nice with Entity Framework (which I've since switched over to dapper).  `SELECT Id, ComputedColumn FROM MyTable WHERE Id = scope_identity()` was actually not even returning a row, but dapper was correctly loading the Id returned by the trigger.  Changed the trigger to return Id and ComputedColumn and everything works great!